# What lens for catalog-quality photos of long guns?

Tags: product-photography, lens-recommendation

I want to take high quality photos of long guns (rifles, shotguns, etc.) having dimensions of approx. 6in.(15cm) x 66in.(168cm) for purposes of catalog display and insurance archives.  These are typically shot on a bench, horizontally, with a solid color background.

Can anyone give me a recommendation of what lens and settings would be good for this type of shot?  Thank you for your consideration!

Comment: Note that the most important thing here isn't the lens — it is, by far, the *lighting*.

Answer (score 7):

@mattdm nailed it: I've been shooting long guns for a decade.  The single most important factor is light.  For a catalog-quality shot you need lots of good diffuse light, which you can get by bouncing a speedlight off a white ceiling or wall, or by shooting in daylight with reflectors.  For black guns you need to go between +1 and +2 EV to bring out detail.  To maximize sharpness you want to stop down to about f/8.  Finally, to avoid perspective distortion (assuming you're not using a tilt-shift lens) you typically want to get the camera perpendicular to the subject.

Depending on the quality of the lens at that point you may find that you need to crop tightly to avoid all the possible lens distortions, although if you have a good lens profile you can correct a lot of that in post.

Examples: Here's one in high sunlight balanced with a speedlight from the front-left quarter:
[image]

Here's a black gun done indoors with a speedlight:
[image]

Both of these happen to have been done on an APS-C body with my shortest prime: a mid-grade Sigma 28mm EX DG lens.  I almost always go to that lens because any longer and I can't fit a long gun in frame at a convenient distance.

So if I were making lens suggestions I would say pick a prime *no longer than* 28mm for crop sensor, and preferably closer to 20mm; or 28-35mm for full-frame cameras.  No need to pay up for extreme apertures: it's better to put more money into lighting for this type of shooting.

Comment: While this is a good answer, it would be better if you expanded on the lens selected and why. In particular because that seems to be the focus of the original question.

Comment: Good point; just added a paragraph on that.

Answer (score 1):

Basically any lens with a low amount of distortion would be best, but it depends on your studio, camera body, and working distance.

As for settings, there are no magic settings. See: http://www.bythom.com/magicsettings.htm

I would recommend making an attempt with what equipment you have and posting your results here, with a question specially asking what problems you are encountering. If you have no equipment yet, renting is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the space, use a longer lens - somewhere in the medium-telephoto range and sit well back. If you use a wide angle lens you will have nasty perspective and distortion issues at both the stock and muzzle.

If your workspace has an atrium with a balcony you may find it easier to mount the camera on the balcony rail and lay the rifle flat on a table. With many guns this will be faster than mounting it on a stand.